# Share base class with all entities return Id property by expression

Tags: c#, lambda

This may not be possible but we have an existing database where all the Id properties are the table name with Id appended.  I would like to change all our entities to inherit from a BaseEntity class and have a single property called Id on it and in the constructor specify what the property is.  For example:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public User() : base(x => x.UserId)
    {}

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way of getting this working as nothing I have tried will compile.  Many thanks

Comment: Personnaly, I dislike having `User.UserId` property. Just `User.Id` seems pretty fine to me

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BaseEntity(int id)
    {
       Id = id;
    }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public User(int id) : base(id)
    {
        UserId = id;
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public User(int id) : base()
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int UserId { get { return base.Id; } set { base.Id = value; } }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it fits user requirements but I'd set the `BaseEntity.Id` property to `protected` in your example.. Maybe..

Comment: I thought about doing that, but no reason to not make it public?  Usually I would have all the base class stuff protected, and then override but for the other tables, they may just have Id, and not require an override.  Good point though!